# grub2 prompt: "grub>" is changed to ">"

Tags: command-line, grub2, scripts, keyboard, prompt

So I am at login screen of GNU GRUB 2.02 launched from USB stick. Its prompt is "**grub>**". When I type "*ls*" I see all my disks: *hd0, hd1, hd2*; *hd0* is my USB stick, *hd2* is my main disk. But if I boot from the main disk, it is treated by its own grub as *hd0*. So no consistency. If I want to jump to another disk, how grubs of two disks will interact?
When I type with error, answer is "*error: invalid file name `..`*", then I typed "*ls .,{[]´~*" and I got prompt "**>**" instead of "**grub>**", and no idea how to leave "**>**" prompt. Is it useful? Then I pushed *TAB* and got a long list of "*possible commands*", maybe unfinished, as the screen is blocked: no input. And how to copy that list? can I change keyboard? it is English by default.

Comment: The values are controlled by BIOS/uEFI, if you change devices, your BIOS/uEFI will change to reflect the new devices it sees. That is the reason UUIDs are recommend as they are consistent across machines and BIOS/uEFI settings, but you can only take advantage of UUIDs once the system has booted. Your question isn't about Ubuntu, but about the firwmare on your machine as I read it. We don't know the make or model of your hardware, nor the firmware it uses that your question is mostly about. You don't even mention any on-topic OS, only a bootloader used by many OSes and one option used by Ubuntu

Comment: I see your point, but it is not logical: GRUB is the first step to boot into OS, among them is Ubuntu. Grub is using its own script language, which may differ from BASH in Ubuntu. So Ubuntu should be able to decrypt Grub messages; and my question was about safety of passage from Grub to Ubuntu and their mutual understanding. And your point is that my question is irrelevant to Ubuntu. I see here (site askubuntu) many questions relevant to Grub, mostly treating grub.cfg, but rarely about manual passage from Grub to Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu is available on many architectures; GNU grub is one of the bootloaders and is used by default for *amd64* which is probably the most used architecture by far, but as not architectures have been able to use `grub`, it's not used by all Ubuntu (it's significance is increasing with time as lilo/syslinux reduec). GNU grub has it's own syntax (grub1 differed to grub2 so it's varied over time) being defined by it's creators (it's a GNU program that is used by Ubuntu). It's a bootloader that has completed it's task when Ubuntu is running (Ubuntu does have some created tools like `update-grub`)